# Using Parameters<Fn> where Fn extends a function Type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

This is related to a problem I am having with Redux Saga generators. One of the definitions they have for `call` is (excluding the implementation):

```js
// this is taken from redux saga and cannot be changed
function call<Fn extends (...args: any[]) => any>(
  fn: Fn,
  ...args: Parameters<Fn>
): CallEffect<SagaReturnType<Fn>> { ... }
```

I am trying to call this as follows:

```js
function test<F extends (a: string, b: number) => any>(f: F) {
  return call(f, 'a', 0)
}
```

At which point I get the error: Argument of type '["a", 0]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Parameters<F>'.

But if `F` extends `(a: string, b: number) => any`, shouldn't that be assignable?

Comment: If I read this correctly all parameters will have to be of the same type for it to be assignable. Only types that are assignable to each other, for example it could work if the arguments are all of a specific interface. Your way around this is to manually check each parameter for the type during runtime.

Comment: If you can't change `call` or `test`'s call signatures, then you'll need a type assertion or a widening, because the compiler can't do the higher order analysis to determine that `(...a: Parameters<F>)=>ReturnType<F>)` can be substituted for `F` when `F` is an unresolved generic type.  [Here](https://tsplay.dev/WK8rDw) are the options I see; do any of those work for you?  If so I'm happy to write up an answer.

Comment: I can't change the `call` signature, it is from redux saga, but I can change `test`. The real `call` function returns a value and infers the return type from `Fn`. Widening or asserting causes the real return type to be lost and replaced by `any`. So I guess I'm left with `test<R>(f:  (a: string, b: number) => R)`

Comment: @fredrik Parameters will return a tuple if the types are different. i.e.:
`type F = (a: string, b: number) => boolean`, `type P = Parameters<F>` gives `type P = [a: string, b: number]`

Answer (score 1):

Conditional types such as `Prameters` generally don't play very well with unresolved generic types. Since the type is not definitely known typescript will generally not evaluate conditional types.

You might work around it using a slightly different signature to `call`:

```
function call<A extends any[], R>(
  fn: (...a: A) => R,
  ...args: A
): void {}

function test<F extends (a: string, b: number) => any>(f: F): void {
  call(f, 'a', 0)
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBAhgGzQHgIKIKYAeUeYAJgM6IpgCeA2gLoA0iASgHwAUAUIosGABciTgDpxKYdgCUiALzs2TXonGiUAJwDm5Kd2nCAbnBilEAbwC+3bqEiwEiYuSiYAYviIkKIyYhcaMGBaLABGwmAgALaheBqyClS0XMDCbgaIxqYWKqgYnMAsAOQoRSwADNLclkA)

Comment: Unfortunately, that signature for call is taken directly from redux saga, so i can't really change it.

Answer (score 0):

The engine isn't quite smart enough to know that ['a', 0] is assignable to `Parameters<F>` when `F` is an unresolved generic.

We can work around this by first assigning `f` to a variable with the concrete type that we care about:

```
function test<F extends (x: string, y: number) => any>(f: F) {
  const f2: (x: string, y: number) => any = f;
  return call(f2, 'a', 0)
}
```